# Slam it all! (imported character abilities missing)

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just imported my character from ME2, and was operating under the assumption that  when one imports a character the abilities from ME2 remain.

While that *is* true for some of my abilities (like incendiary), I lost my slammin' Slam ability.

Instead of Slam, I received some other ability.  My question is: Is there some way I can keep Slam?  Is it still there but a higher level?  Can I do anything with my ME2 character to help the situation?  Any recommendations on what can replace slam??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bonus powers and Loyalty powers like Slam and Reave do not transfer.

Only abilities gained and unlocked as part of the progression of your chosen class will transfer over.

You can learn **Slam** specifically from Javik if you have the *From Ashes* DLC installed.

Comment: Note: You can unlock bonus powers in ME3 in various ways, and train in them by using the bed in the medical lab of Normandy. I haven't found any info about how to unlock Slam specifically though.

Answer (score 1):

Slam is a bonus power given by the prothian Jarvik in the add on that comes with the collectors edition of the game... I use it all the time. It rocks.